"Flattening" a 2D STM image by subtracting an Nth order polynomial without typing out all the terms for each N?
I have some scanning tunneling microscopy (STM) topography images that I need to flatten. I have found that for some data I need a 4th order polynomial, but in other cases a lower order works better.
I use np.linalg.lstsq()' for the fitting, but currently I type out all the polynomials for each order by hand which works but is vulnerable to typos and difficult to generalize to larger N (if I ever need to do that in the future).
I'm aware of np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d() which should work for a bi-quartic polynomial (5 × 5 = 25 coefficients), but perhaps not in this application for a 4th order polynomial (15 coefficients).
Simple example of flattening:

Python script:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def flatten(array, order=1):
    b = array.flatten()
    s0, s1 = array.shape
    x, y = [q.flatten() for q in np.mgrid[-1:1:s0*1j, -1:1:s1*1j]]
    c = np.ones_like(x)

    if order == 0:
        a = np.array([c]).T
        coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
        c1 = coeff[0]
        f = c1 * np.ones_like(x)

    elif order == 1:
        a = np.array([x, y, c]).T
        coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
        c1, c2, c3 = coeff
        f = c1*x + c2*y + c3

    elif order == 2:
        a = np.array([x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y, c]).T
        coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
        c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 = coeff
        f = c1*x**2 + c2*x*y + c3*y**2 + c4*x + c5*y + c6

    elif order == 3:
        a = np.array([x**3, x**2*y, x*y**2, y**3, x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y, c]).T
        coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
        c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10 = coeff
        f = (c1*x**3 + c2*x**2*y + c3*x*y**2 + c4*y**3 +
              c5*x**2 + c6*x*y + c7*y**2 + c8*x + c9*y + c10)

    elif order == 4:
        a = np.array([x**4, x**3*y, x**2*y**2, x*y**3, y**4,
                       x**3, x**2*y, x*y**2, y**3, x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y, c]).T
        coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
        c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15 = coeff
        f = (c1*x**4 + c2*x**3*y + c3*x**2*y**2 + c4*x*y**3 + c5*y**4 +
              c6*x**3 + c7*x**2*y + c8*x*y**2 + c9*y**3 +
              c10*x**2 + c11*x*y + c12*y**2 + c13*x + c14*y + c15)

    flat = f.reshape(*array.shape)
    flattened = array - flat

    return flattened, coeff


y, x = np.mgrid[0:201, 0:201] 
z = np.exp(-( (y - 35)**2 + (x - 85)**2) / (2*45**2))

order = 4

zf, coeff = flatten(z, order=order)

if True:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=[10, 4])
    titles = 'original', 'flattened, n=' + str(order)
    for ax, thing, title in zip(axes, (z, zf), titles):
        hh = np.abs(thing).max()
        im = ax.imshow(thing, origin='lower', cmap='RdBu', vmin=-hh, vmax=hh)
        fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
        ax.set_title(title)
    plt.show()


"need a 4th order polynomial, but in other cases a lower order works better." Could you shed some light on what metric would reveal that one setup is better than another? It feels like we should be able to readily justify the equation we're fitting in terms of the underlying physics, and I'm not yet seeing that here. If there is tilt or scan curvature, could we maybe pre-process to remove those confounds prior to flattening?


Lets see how you build the array to see how to DRY the code:

a = np.array([                                                                                          c]).T
a = np.array([                                                                                    x, y, c]).T
a = np.array([                                                                   x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y, c]).T
a = np.array([                                       x**3, x**2*y, x*y**2, y**3, x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y, c]).T
a = np.array([x**4, x**3*y, x**2*y**2, x*y**3, y**4, x**3, x**2*y, x*y**2, y**3, x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y, c]).T


Ok so we can see the list grows in the same way each time.
Lets invert the list (a[::-1]) to more easily build the list and see how the segments grow.
[c] + [y, x] + [y**2, x*y, x**2] + [y**3, x*y**2, x**2*y, x**3] + [y**4, x*y**3, x**2*y**2, x**3*y, x**4]

The algorithm to build each segment is pretty simple.
We can change each array item to the form y**a * x**b.
Where b = order - a.
So something like:
def build_array(c, x, y, order):
    output = [c]
    for size in range(1, 1 + order):
        for i in range(1 + size):
            output.append(x**i * y**(size-i))
    return output[::-1]


Lets see how we can DRY the lstsq line

coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)


Ok, nice and simple.

Lets see how we can DRY the f line
Lets preface the following section with; I don't know what np.linalg.lstsq does and I haven't looked at the docs. I'm just going off patterns.

c1 = coeff[0]
f = c1 * np.ones_like(x)

c1, c2, c3 = coeff
f = c1*x + c2*y + c3

c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 = coeff
f = c1*x**2 + c2*x*y + c3*y**2 + c4*x + c5*y + c6


Looks like the c names are not consistent. So lets invert the names:
c1 = coeff[0]
f = c1 * np.ones_like(x)

c3, c2, c1 = coeff
f = c3*x + c2*y + c1

c6, c5, c4, c3, c2, c1 = coeff
f = c6*x**2 + c5*x*y + c4*y**2 + c3*x + c2*y + c1

Lets build a visual comparison with the adjustment again:
f =                                                                                                                                                         c1 * np.ones_like(x)
f =                                                                                                                                           c3*x + c2*y + c1
f =                                                                                                              c6*x**2 + c5*x*y + c4*y**2 + c3*x + c2*y + c1
f =                                                                 c10*x**3 + c9*x**2*y + c8*x*y**2 + c7*y**3 + c6*x**2 + c5*x*y + c4*y**2 + c3*x + c2*y + c1
f = c15*x**4 + c14*x**3*y + c13*x**2*y**2 + c12*x*y**3 + c11*y**4 + c10*x**3 + c9*x**2*y + c8*x*y**2 + c7*y**3 + c6*x**2 + c5*x*y + c4*y**2 + c3*x + c2*y + c1

The pattern is grows consistently and reminds me of the pattern with a.
Lets compare the final f with the final a:
a = [   x**4,      x**3*y,      x**2*y**2,      x*y**3,      y**4,      x**3,     x**2*y,     x*y**2,     y**3,     x**2,     x*y,     y**2,     x,     y,       c]
f = c15*x**4 + c14*x**3*y + c13*x**2*y**2 + c12*x*y**3 + c11*y**4 + c10*x**3 + c9*x**2*y + c8*x*y**2 + c7*y**3 + c6*x**2 + c5*x*y + c4*y**2 + c3*x + c2*y + c1

Ok looks like we can just reuse a which we build earlier.

We need to replace the c with np.ones_like(x).
We can use zip to go through both arrays and then multiply the values together.
We can functools.reduce to sum the values.

a[-1] = np.ones_like(x)
f = functools.reduce(
    operator.add,
    [
        c * a_
        for c, a_ in zip(coeff, a)
    ],
)



Lets bundle all the code together:
NOTE: All code in the answer is untested
def build_array(c, x, y, order):
    output = [c]
    for size in range(1, 1 + order):
        for i in range(1 + size):
            output.append(x**i * y**(size-i))
    return output[::-1]


def flatten(array, order=1):
    b = array.flatten()
    s0, s1 = array.shape
    x, y = [q.flatten() for q in np.mgrid[-1:1:s0*1j, -1:1:s1*1j]]
    c = np.ones_like(x)

    a_python = build_array(c, x, y, order)
    a = np.array(a_python).T
    coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
    a_python[-1] = np.ones_like(x)
    f = functools.reduce(
        operator.add,
        [
            c * a_
            for c, a_ in zip(coeff, a_python)
        ],
    )
    flat = f.reshape(*array.shape)
    flattened = array - flat

    return flattened, coeff


As requested by @uhoh we can provide a selection to filter the values. Such as:
def build_coefficents(c, x, y, order):
    output = [c]
    for size in range(1, 1 + order):
        for i in range(0, 1 + size):
            output.append(x**i * y**(size-i))
    return output[::-1]


def flatten(array, select=None, order=1):
    s0, s1 = array.shape
    x, y = [
        q.flatten()
        for q in np.mgrid[-1:1:s0*1j, -1:1:s1*1j]
    ]
    b = array.flatten()
    c = np.ones_like(x)
    a_python = build_coefficents(c, x, y, order)

    if select is None:
        a = np.array(a_python).T
        coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)
    elif not isinstance(select, np.ndarray):
        raise TypeError(f"select must be of type NDArray; {type(select)}")
    elif select.shape != array.shape:
        raise ValueError(f"select must be the same shape as the array; {select.shape} != {array.shape}")
    else:
        x, y = [
            q[select].flatten()
            for q in np.mgrid[-1:1:s0*1j, -1:1:s1*1j]
        ]
        b = array[select].flatten()
        c = np.ones_like(x)
        a_python_sel = build_coefficents(c, x, y, order)
        a = np.array(a_python_sel).T
        coeff, r, rank, ss = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)

    a_python[-1] = np.ones(s0 * s1)
    f = functools.reduce(
        operator.add,
        [c * a_ for c, a_ in zip(coeff, a_python)],
    )
    flattened = array - f.reshape(*array.shape)
    return flattened, coeff

